# Multicore generation of plots

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plot, multicore

I have a `for` loop which generates via `png()` and `dev.off()` a plot and saves it the working directory.

The loop I have is similar to the following **example**

```
test.df<-data.frame(id=1:25000, x=rnorm(25000),y=rnorm(25000))

for (i in test.df$id){
  plot(test.df$x[test.df$id==i], test.df$y[test.df$id==i], xlab="chi",ylab="psi")
}
```

The `for` loop will run and generate thousands of plots. Is it possible to make it run parallel on all 8 cores of my system so that I can get the plots faster?

PS. The code is an **example**. My original problem and plots are much more complicated. Don't go viral on the example.

Comment: I believe that it is.  You haven't given any code so here's a link to a blog I did on parallel computing.  http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/parallelization-speed-up-functions-in-a-package/  This approach was using a windows machine.  Note the links that describe other approaches.

Comment: I have added an example. I don't use a function for the plotting and the *ply family as well as it's parallel optimized cousins don't fit in my example. What I think I have to do is assign each iteration of the `for` loop to different core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you are using a new version of R, then this should be straightforward. The trick is to create a function that can be run on any core in any order. First we create our data frame:

```
test.df = data.frame(id=1:250, x=rnorm(250),y=rnorm(250))
```

Next we create the function that runs on each core:

```
#I could also pass the row or the entire data frame
myplot = function(id) {
  fname = paste0("/tmp/plot", id, ".png")
  png(fname)
  plot(test.df$x[id], test.df$y[id], 
      xlab="chi",ylab="psi")
  dev.off()
  return(fname)
}
```

Then I load the `parallel` package (this comes with base R)

```
library(parallel)
```

and then use `mclapply`

```
no_of_cores = 8
##Non windows
mclapply(1:nrow(test.df), myplot, 
         mc.cores = no_of_cores)

##All OS's
cl = makeCluster(no_of_cores)
clusterExport(cl, "test.df")
parSapply(cl, 1:nrow(test.df), myplot)
stopCluster(cl)
```

There are two advantages here:

1. The package `parallel` comes with R, so we don't need to install anything extra
2. We can switch off the "parallel" part:

   ```
   sapply(1:nrow(test.df), myplot)
   ```

Comment: Won't this be delayed for write unless you can somehow provide a physical drive for each separate core?

Comment: @mdsumner That is a good point, and to be honest I'm not entirely sure. However, if the bottle neck is doing data manipulation for the plots, you'll still get a speed-up. The OP will just have test.

Answer (score 5):

With `foreach` package you have to modify you core code minimally. Also you can choose any backend of your choice regarding OS or other issues.

```
##
## Working dir and data generation
##
setwd("/path/to")
N <- 25000
test.df<-data.frame(id=1:N, x=rnorm(N),y=rnorm(N))

##
## Making a cluster
##
require(doSNOW) # Or any other backend of your choice
NC <- 8         # Number of nodes in cluster, i.e. cores
cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost", NC), type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

## 
## Core loop
##
foreach(i=1:N) %dopar% {
  png(paste("plot",i,".png",sep=""))
  plot(test.df$x[test.df$id==i], test.df$y[test.df$id==i], xlab="chi",ylab="psi")
  dev.off()
}

##
## Stop cluster
##
stopCluster(cl)
```

It's easy to go for one core: just substitute `%dopar%` with `%do%`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `mclapply` is not supported on windows,
I give a solution for windows users, using `parallel` package.

```
cl <- makeCluster(8)
parSapply(cl, 1:20, fun, fun.args)
```